# HTML 5 Browser camera permission

Tags: javascript, html, browser, camera, microphone

I have web application that uses WEB RTC for video communication between two peers. Everything works fine, but we have one headache in production.

The thing is that when browser asks for camera and microphone permission, the pop up is often ignored by users and therefor they are getting frustrated why their video is not shown. So i am wondering if there is some library that can predict where the permission pop up is shown, so i can show some arrow from my html and make it more obvious?

Comment: Im looking for exactly the same thing. I have seen other sites show a banner under the address bar stating where to click to allow permissions. Did you ever find a library?

Comment: Apparently nothing out of the box, as i remember we ended up improvising solutions for each browser separately.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the browser engine implementation of getUserMedia function requires user permission to access the webcam.The video data stream starts only after user action.I think we cannot access webcam without user access permission. 
If you want to avoid user permission then we have to avoid permission only inside the html rendering engine.

Comment: Yes, i am completely aware that we cant avoid camera permission. What i am asking is how to make this permission pop up more obvious for the user.

Comment: There is no way to customize the security pop up , but before security pop up you can manage to show a message "Please click allow or accept on Security pop up".

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <button onclick="askPermission()">click me</button>
        <video></video>
```

```js
     function askPermission(){

         //add constraints object
         var constraints = {
             audio:true,
             video:true};

         //call getUserMedia
         navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(mediaStream){

             var video = document.querySelector('video');
             video.srcObject = mediaStream;
             video.play();
             }).catch(function(err){
                 console.log("There's an error!" + err.message);
             })

     }
```